# How to create Complex Class in python which does all the functions related to Complex numbers like (add, subtract, multiply, divide etc)

Tags: python-3.x, class, complexity-theory

Please help :/. How to create Complex Class in python which does all the functions related to Complex numbers like (add, subtract, multiply, divide etc). Also, other functions like power, norm etc.

Comment: Why do you need a class to use mathematical operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

from copy import *
from math import sqrt

class Complex:

```
def __init__(self, re, im):

    self.re = deepcopy(re)
    self.im = deepcopy(im)

def __str__(self):

    r1 = self.re
    i1 = self.im
    if(r1 > 0 and i1 > 0):
        r1 = str(r1)
        r1 +='+'
        if(abs(i1) != 1):
            i1 = str(i1)
            i1 += 'i'
        else:
            i1 = 'i'
    elif(r1 == 0 and i1 == 0):
        return '0'
    elif(r1 <= 0 and i1<0):
        if(r1 == 0):
            r1 = str(r1)
            r1 = ''
        if(i1 == -1):
            i1 = str(i1)
            i1 = '-i'
        else:
            i1 = str(i1)
            i1 += 'i'
    elif(r1 <= 0 and i1>0):
        if(r1 == 0):
            r1 = str(r1)
            r1 = ''
        else:
            r1 = str(r1)
            r1 += '+'
        if(i1 == 1):
            i1 = str(i1)
            i1 = 'i'
        else:
            i1 = str(i1)
            i1 += 'i'
    elif(r1 > 0 and i1 < 0):
        i1 = self.im
        i1 = str(i1)
        if(i1 != '-1'):
            i1 += 'i'
        else:
            i1 = '-i'
    if(i1 == 0):
        i1 = ''

    self.__repr__()
    ans = str(r1) + str(i1)
    return ans



def __add__(self, other):

    r1 = self.re + other.re
    i1 = self.im + other.im
    ans = Complex(r1,i1)
    return ans

def __sub__(self, other):
    r1 = self.re - other.re
    i1 = self.im - other.im
    ans = Complex(r1,i1)
    return ans

def __mul__(self, other):

    r1 = self.re * other.re
    r2 = self.im * other.im
    ex1 = r1 - r2
    i1 = self.re * other.im
    i2 = self.im * other.re
    ex2 = i1 + i2
    c = Complex(ex1,ex2)
    return c

def __truediv__(self, other):

    r1 = self.re * other.re
    r2 = self.im * other.im
    denom = other.re**2 + other.im**2
    ex1 = int((r1 + r2) / denom)
    i1 = self.re * other.im * (-1)
    i2 = self.im * other.re
    ex2 = int((i1 + i2) / denom)
    c = Complex(ex1, ex2)
    return c

def __eq__(self,other):

    if(self.re==other.re and self.im==other.im):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def norm(self):

    r1 = self.re
    i1 = self.im
    p1 = r1*r1
    p2 = i1*i1
    c = p1 + p2
    ans = int(sqrt(c))
    return ans
```

def cpow(c, n):

```
r = Complex(1,0)
for i in range(n):
    r = r.__mul__(c)
return r
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
zero = Complex(0,0)
one = Complex(1,0)
iota = Complex(0,1)
minus_one = Complex(-1, 0)
minus_iota = Complex(0, -1)
c1 = Complex(1,1)
v = Complex(0,-1)
x = Complex(2, 3)
y = Complex(4, 5)
z = x + y
print(z)
print(x-y)
print(x*y)
print(x/y)
print(iota)
```

Hope this helps mate.